# Temporarily access to an entry

Tags: security

I have an entry that is currently password protected and I am looking for a way to give access to this entry to non-craft users temporarily access either by a token or something else. Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You can share a temporary link to an unpublished entry by clicking on the "Share" button, right next to the "Live Preview" button.

**Craft 2:**

[image: "Share" button in Craft 2]

**Craft 3:**

[image: "Share" button in Craft 3]

This creates a link with a token that will expire automatically. The length of time that the token lasts for can be controlled with the [defaultTokenDuration](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#defaultTokenDuration) config setting.